# Laptop screen tearing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, screen, tearing

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Asus laptop and I am pretty new to the OS. I noticed that when I watch any videos in both Mozilla and Chrome, they don't run as smoothly as they would in Windows. Turning off hardware acceleration doesn't seem to fix the problem.

I'm using GeForce GTX 950M.

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers for the graphics card. Open Additional drivers, select and apply the recommended version. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

try running these commands in terminal:

```
\#!/bin/bash

nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="$(nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode -t|tr '\n' ' '|sed -e 's/.*:: \(.*\)/\1\n/g' -e 's/}/, ForceCompositionPipeline = On}/g')" > /dev/null
```

i just found this solution and it fixed it for me. Basically it had something to do with the OS using graphics drivers from your cpu and your gpu for various different functions at the same time. I don't know really though. However this worked for me so hopefully it does for you too. Otherwise it may be a driver issue and you'll need to reinstall that.